# What is the vacuum solution of Dirac equation?

Tags: field-theory, dirac-equation

What am I generally asking is what solution of massive Dirac equation could be considered vacuum solution

Comment: What do you mean by "vacuum solution"? The Dirac equation is just a differential equation, and it has general solution(s). What characterizes a "vacuum" solution among these?

Comment: That is my question. There're solutions that are considered particles and antiparticles. But what solution could be physically considered a vacuum state?

Comment: I don't understand: The Dirac equation is *either* the equation for the wavefunction of a single particle with spin-1/2, in which case there is no "vacuum" because "no particle" is not an allowed state for "one particle with spin-1/2", *or* it is the equation for a (quantum) field, in which case the solutions don't directly reflect particle states at all, since particle states in QFT are *created* by field operators, not specific solutions to the field equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've gotten a bit mixed up: The vacuum state $|\Omega \rangle$ is not a solution to the Dirac equation just as much as any given initial state $|\psi \rangle$ is not a solution to any equation of motion, because it is not even a function of time $t$. The Dirac equation answers the question: given some initial state (or field, in the interaction or Heisenberg pictures, which are more commonly used in QFT), how does it evolve  forwards in time? It doesn't provide any extra information about the "contents" of a state.

A similar question that you *could* ask: If you moved to the Schrödinger picture, what would be the solution to the dirac equation with initial condition $|\psi_0 \rangle = |\Omega \rangle$? I have never seen this solved, and would be curious about the answer as well.

Comment: Possibly of interest with regards to your second paragraph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_functional (It doesn't directly give the answer for the Dirac equation but does show how it works for a scalar field).